# Who know how to implement the 2D bone animation showed in the game?

Tags: animation, 2d, game-physics

I wonder how do they implement the bone animation in the flash game http://www.foddy.net/athletics.swf
Do you know any study materials which I can start to learn 2D bone system from? I just implemented a avatar system by compose multiple bitmaps in each frame(similar with maple story), but some guys tell me that, a bone system can save more art resources, so I want to learn some thing about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Box2D. It's a 2D physics engine that does what you want.

Here's a link: http://www.box2d.org/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at at [Dragonbones](http://dragonbones.com/) to do bone animations with your images.  It's easy, FREE and can export to multiple file formats.  You import your images into a library, create an armiture of bones and then pose the armiture in one or more animations.